# pyspark get week number of month by starting week on Thursday

Tags: pyspark

I need to get the weekday of a month. However the starting day of the week should be Thursday.

The data is given below

[image]

Currently my code gives the starting day as Sunday.

```
df = df.withColumn("Week_Number",date_format(to_date("inv_dt", "yyyy-MM-dd"), "W"))
```

However I want the week to start on a Thursday

Comment: Can u provide the dataset?

Comment: @PrathikKini I have edited the question to show the dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Consider creating a User Defined Function (UDF) to handle the special case.

For example, the following UDF handles special case when a week starts other than Sunday.

The argument `start_day_of_week` takes an integer as [isoweekday](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday), where Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def week_number(date_str, start_day_of_week=7):
    @udf("long")
    def _week_number(date_str):
        from datetime import datetime, date
        d = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')     # compatible with Python2
        wd_d1 = date(d.year, d.month, 1).isoweekday()
        offset = (wd_d1 - start_day_of_week + 7 ) % 7
        return (d.day - 1 + offset) // 7 + 1
    return _week_number(date_str)
```

Note: code above is tested with Python3 (3.7.3) and Python (2.7.15) in PySpark (2.4.4). By default PySpark starts with Python (2.7.15). To use Python3, start PySpark with `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 pyspark`, or add `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` to startup script.

If the UDF only get used in Python3, one can simply use `d = date.fromisoformat(date_str)` and only import `date` from `datetime`.

**Demo**

Consider input data like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

inv_dt = [ '2018-09-{:02d}'.format(x) for x in range(1, 31) ]

# if with Pandas installed
import pandas as pd
df_pd = pd.DataFrame({'inv_dt':inv_dt})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)

# if without Pandas
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
df = spark.createDataFrame(inv_dt, StringType()).withColumnRenamed('value', 'inv_dt')

df.show()

# +----------+
# |    inv_dt|
# +----------+
# |2018-09-01|
# |2018-09-02|
# |2018-09-03|
# |2018-09-04|
# |2018-09-05|
# |2018-09-06|
# |2018-09-07|
# |2018-09-08|
# |2018-09-09|
# |2018-09-10|
# |2018-09-11|
# |2018-09-12|
# |2018-09-13|
# |2018-09-14|
# |2018-09-15|
# |2018-09-16|
# |2018-09-17|
# |2018-09-18|
# |2018-09-19|
# |2018-09-20|
# +----------+
# only showing top 20 rows
```

And call our UDF `week_number` just like other Spark SQL functions such as `date_format`.
We can compare our UDF output `week_number("inv_dt", 7)` with Spark builtin `date_format(to_date("inv_dt", "yyyy-MM-dd"), "W")`.

```
( df    
    .withColumn("Day_of_Week", date_format(to_date("inv_dt", "yyyy-MM-dd"), "u"))
    .withColumn("Week_Number_Sun_ref", date_format(to_date("inv_dt", "yyyy-MM-dd"), "W"))
    .withColumn("Week_Number_Sun", week_number("inv_dt", 7))
    .withColumn("Day_of_Week_Thu", week_number("inv_dt", 4))
    .withColumn("Day_of_Week_Mon", week_number("inv_dt", 1))
).show()

# +----------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
# |    inv_dt|Day_of_Week|Week_Number_Sun_ref|Week_Number_Sun|Day_of_Week_Thu|Day_of_Week_Mon|
# +----------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
# |2018-09-01|          6|                  1|              1|              1|              1|
# |2018-09-02|          7|                  2|              2|              1|              1|
# |2018-09-03|          1|                  2|              2|              1|              2|
# |2018-09-04|          2|                  2|              2|              1|              2|
# |2018-09-05|          3|                  2|              2|              1|              2|
# |2018-09-06|          4|                  2|              2|              2|              2|
# |2018-09-07|          5|                  2|              2|              2|              2|
# |2018-09-08|          6|                  2|              2|              2|              2|
# |2018-09-09|          7|                  3|              3|              2|              2|
# |2018-09-10|          1|                  3|              3|              2|              3|
# |2018-09-11|          2|                  3|              3|              2|              3|
# |2018-09-12|          3|                  3|              3|              2|              3|
# |2018-09-13|          4|                  3|              3|              3|              3|
# |2018-09-14|          5|                  3|              3|              3|              3|
# |2018-09-15|          6|                  3|              3|              3|              3|
# |2018-09-16|          7|                  4|              4|              3|              3|
# |2018-09-17|          1|                  4|              4|              3|              4|
# |2018-09-18|          2|                  4|              4|              3|              4|
# |2018-09-19|          3|                  4|              4|              3|              4|
# |2018-09-20|          4|                  4|              4|              4|              4|
# +----------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
# only showing top 20 rows
#
```

Comment: It's possible to do the same with built-in Pyspark functions.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Perhaps you meant to only use functions within module `pyspark.sql.functions`? With intermediate columns we could do it, but it will be less elegant than UDF. PySpark itself is designed to encourage mix with Python builtin functions or even Python packages, bridged by UDF.

Comment: It's possible to wrap the process in a function similar to your UDF. There's no need to write out the intermediate columns. It should be quite a bit faster as well.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Perhaps you were thinking of  `map` or `flatMap`? Along that approach, one has to ensure the function is pickle-able to be broadcasted to workers, which just make things messier. I am interested to see, and welcome to add to the answer, if you have a faster and cleaner solution :D However, IMHO, in order to claim "being faster", one needs to benchmark to prove it ...

Comment: No, you can simply use the methods `pyspark.sql.functions` all the way, and it should be faster since they are "native" functions..

Comment: @absolutelydevastated When you use PySpark, python functions are "native" on PySpark workers, please check the implementation of [`date_format`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/eb037a8180be4ab7570eda1fa9cbf3c84b92c3f7/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L913) and UDFs in the [Worker implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/worker.py#L257) . Again, if you have a better solution, welcome to benchmark and then show it ;) If you still have more to talk, let do it in chat...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199201/discussion-between-quar-and-absolutelydevastated).

Answer (score 1):

The "pure" PySpark way is as follows

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def week_number(date_str, start_day_of_week=7):
    day_of_month = F.dayofmonth(date_str)
    first_day = F.date_sub(date_str, day_of_month - 1)
    first_day_day_of_week = F.dayofweek(first_day)
    offset = (first_day_day_of_week - start_day_of_week + 7) % 7
    week_num = F.floor((day_of_month - 1 + offset) / 7) + 1
    return week_num

week_num_from_thurs = df.withColumn('week_num_from_thurs', week_number('inv_dt', 4))
```

It's 2 a.m. and I don't have a local Spark cluster or anything so this might be buggy. Credit should go to @Quar for the solution. I'm just converting Python to the Pyspark SQL API here. Variable names are deliberately verbose.